# Java SSL pass certificate chain as client certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, x509certificate, client-certificates

I want to build up an HTTPS connection with SSL/TLSv1.2.
I have several things loaded.

```
X509Certificate rootCertificate = ...;
X509Certificate intermediateCertificate = ...;
X509Certificate myPublicCertificate = ...;
KeyStore myPrivateKey = ...;


KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyManagerFactory.init(myPrivateKey, "password");
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
URL url = new URL(urlPath);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Now I have to connect to to different servers.

**Connection to Server1 (works)**

Server1 has as Cert Authorities the *rootCertificate* as well as the *intermediateCertificate*. The connection could be established.

**Connection to Server2 (doesn't work)**
Server2 has only the *rootCertificate* as Cert Authorities configured. But *MyPrivateKey* is signed with the *intermediateCertificate* which Server2 doesn't know. During SSL handshake following logs occur:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

How do I configure the connection that it knows *MyPrivateKey* as well as *intermediateCertificate*. Is it even possible??